# Can I use one S3 lifecycle policy to run the rule against multiple bucket prefixes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

I have a bucket with the following logic :

bucket-entry/production/client1/app/temp(the one I want to delete)

now once inside the bucket and production path which are the same I also have e.g. client2, client3, client4 and so on e.g. there also is :

bucket-entry/production/client2/app/temp(the one I want to delete)

What I want to achieve is create a lifecycle policy which will expire the temp path for all of the clients. All the other paths are constants except the client1,client2,client3 path.

Is there any solution on using one lifecycle rule for all temp paths in this case in multiple directories, instead of creating bunch of lifecycle rules?

Comment: Check https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/simplify-your-data-lifecycle-by-using-object-tags-with-amazon-s3-lifecycle/